# Javascript debugging - script works with hard coded variable, not with getElementById('id').value

Tags: javascript, debugging, getelementbyid

I'm trying to debug some javascript I wrote and can't figure out why it's not working.  If I hard code the variables it works fine, but if I use document.getElementById('id').value to get the variable it fails.

The example below works fine but as soon as I un-comment the commented lines it doesn't.  Printing the variables before and after the second section they seem to be identical.

Really don't get what's going on.  Maybe I just need to sleep on it, but if anyone's got suggestions that would be great!

```
roof_width = 5;
roof_depth = 3;
panel_width = 2;
panel_depth = 1;
panel_power = 200;
roof_margin = 0.100;
panel_gap = 0.05;

roof_width = document.getElementById('roof_width').value;
roof_depth = document.getElementById('roof_depth').value;
// panel_width = document.getElementById('panel_width').value;
// panel_depth = document.getElementById('panel_depth').value;
panel_power = document.getElementById('panel_power').value;
// roof_margin = document.getElementById('roof_margin').value;
panel_gap = document.getElementById('panel_gap').value;
```

Comment: and could you please also post the html here?

Comment: and you are sure that you have elements with those IDs? `panel_width`, `panel_depth`, `roof_margin`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and you're right, I should have posted the html, but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to add numbers that are in text boxes? Because of the way JavaScript's variable typing system works (combined with the overloading of the `+` operator), `2 + 2 === 4` (adding numbers) but `'2' + '2' === '22'` (string concatenation). Try changing the lines to, for example:

```
panel_width = parseFloat(document.getElementById('panel_width').value);
```

or alternatively:

```
panel_width = Number(document.getElementById('panel_width').value);
```

This will ensure that JavaScript treats the numbers as numbers rather than as strings.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  I thought it might be because it was treating them as strings but then I read that javascript decides the data type itself.  Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript parameters can't be called in the same way that you're calling HTML elements. In order to call

```
document.getElementById('roof_margin').value;
```

you need to assign 'roof_margin' to an HTML form element.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say that it was getting these from form elements.  Fixed now though thanks to idealmachine.

Answer (score 0):

Pherhaps you have multiple dom elements with the same id? Remember the dom element ID must be unique. I suggest you to use jquery for interacting javascript with html.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  They were unique but the script was treating them as strings instead of floats.  Fixed now thanks to idealmachine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is in an onload function. Otherwise the elements may not have been loaded into the DOM yet.

```
window.onload = funciton(){/* code here */};
```

Comment: The function is called from an onClick event.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  Fixed now thanks to idealmachine.